# Choosing NODE.JS backend,frontend and DBMS

Tags: node.js, express, meteor, database, nosql

I want to build a simple ERP app for my company,i came from PHP MYSQL background, i left PHP and now moving to NODE.JS because it overmatches PHP in many ways, i thought i have to learn NODE.JS,

my company is a meat and poultry importer and has hundreds of product and since it is CATCH WEIGHT INVENTORY SYSTEM, each carton has to be recorded as an individual data, they can be millions of cartons, besides INVENTORY, my app must also has other ERP functionalities such as SALES,PURCHASING,HRD,LOGISTIC and many others.

what i already have in mind, i would use :

- -Node.js then
- -Express / Meteor as backend
- -Angular/React as template engine + D3js (i'm not sure) to visualize various reports
- -various DBMS (i think i cannot rely onto just one DBMS, i have to harness the power both of RDBMS and NoSQL DBMS)

  - MySQL for storing user data
  - Key/Value pair DBMS (ElasticSearch / Redis) for storing hardly ever change data but used often and needs fast access such as data product
  - Graph DBMS (Neo4j) for storing user relation, warehouse structure and product movement
  - Document DBMS (MongoDB) for storing tally weight,product detail and many other document based data.

well chose the right tools and make a good plan is halfway to achieve goal, so i need enlightment from all of you Sir and Mam, give me suggestion what should/shouldn't i choose.

Answer (score 0):

Your stack is okay but you need to re-consider the amount of database in use, you don't need the graph database Mysql can handle that for you and as for your key/value pair DBMS go with MongoDb it is a good key/value pair and document store.No need for the extra database.

Comment: i'm sorry sir, on my previous PHP MYSQL app, i felt quite hard with many table relation and defining foreign key, as i just focused on query and relation path to find the data, i'm very interested about what neo4j team offers, as the relations is much more like human language, and it will ease app scale in the future, how do you think

Comment: OK cool, its always nice to explore and since it's a pain for u, u could go ahead and use noe4j and use meteor.js with react that's a pretty awesome stack